# Article/news ordering by order id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I m having a little trouble coming up with a schema to order and changing order in a article/news management system.

Here goes: 
I have News Object Model as follow:

```
 class News {
   int id;
   string Title;
   string Content;
   string OrderId;
   // trimmed
 }
```

I have CRUD for the object model. and List as follows:

```
Id Title Order
1. Foo    -+
2. Bar    -+
3. Glah   -+
```

What i want to do is when user clicks on - for first news, i want to replace 1 and 2 orderid and of course display as well.

well how do i do this on server side? lets say for 1. item order id is 1 , how do i find the first item that has a higher order id then this one?

Or take 2. Bar, when i click on - , how do i find/replace order ids with first one. or i click on + how do i replace order id of this news with 3. Glah ?

is there a better way of doing this?

There are also some UI where user drags and drops ? any pointers on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user changes the location of an item, the server needs to know which item was changed and what it's new position is. In the code below, I'm using a List to figure out the new positons. In this sample code, newPosition is the new zero-based position and selectedArticle is the article that was moved.

```
List<Article> articles = LoadSortedArticles()
articles.Remove(selectedArticle);
articles.Insert(newPosition, selectedArticle);
UpdateArticles(articles);
```

After running, the article's index within the list tells you its new position. That applies to all articles in the list and works the same for a drag/drop UI. I don't know entity framework, but if you can map the orderId field in the database to the index of the article in the list, then you should be good to go.

I hope this is at least able to give you some ideas. Maybe someone else can give a solution specific to entity framework, but I think putting the articles into a sorted list and letting the list do the work might be the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach here would be to implement a `Swap` method that takes two `News` objects and swaps their `OrderId`, which I am assuming is numeric.

So the idea would be that you would pass this method the object that was clicked on, as well as either the one above (if the user clicked `+`) or the one below (if they clicked `-`). If you do it this way then you avoid the task of trying to find the next or previous item.

In the case of drag and drop, the task is a little different. You would first need to retrieve all the items between (and including) the item being dragged and the drop target, ordered by `OrderId`. From there you swap the dragged item with the next or previous item (depending on direction), and continue doing so until you have swapped it with the drop target.